# I tried to fix my Kent Seachange, but when I pedal the wheel shimmies over to the right-hand side

Tags: brakes, parts, coaster

It’s not loose, or misaligned on the axle. It just moves to the right and jams against the frame. Did I forget a part?

[image: From Walmart link]

<sub>( From https://www.walmart.com/ip/Kent-Bicycles-Sea-Change-Men-s-26-in-Beach-Cruiser-Bicycle-Silver/760256796 )</sub>

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm sure one of the gurus on here will have some ideas, but in the meantime it will probably help if you can provide more details. This might include photos (or even video) or an indication of make and model. If you haven't seen it yet, you may want to have a look at Sutherland's book available to download from here: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/sutherland.html If you don't know the make and model, it might help you identify which "type" it is.

Comment: @pateksan I may eventually, but let’s start with the easy way.

Comment: My knowledge of coaster brakes is limited. However, I believe there are a few "types", or "technologies", and it might be hard to help you without knowing what you have. But who knows, we do have some geniuses on here. Good luck

Comment: Well, you do need to make it a little easier on us as well. This site is used as a resource and even a reference for others, and as such, documenting the problem thoroughly is important. It provides us with the information to get the correct and best answer AND makes the question clear enough that someone else can determine whether your problem duplicates theirs.  The answer(s) provided here are not just for you, but for the entire global cycling community.

Comment: @Ted Hohl It’s a Kent Seachange, for what that’s worth. I have no idea who builds their coaster brakes, which kind they are or even if I bought or am replacing the right part.

Comment: @EthanMiller, put that information in the body of the question you posted. I am not a coaster brake expert in the least, but there are some on this site that see them more frequently (shop owners and shop/personal mechanics). You can edit the question to add that information.  And if you have access to a camera, an image or two can be invaluable for these experts.  Without them for questions like these, they would only be speculative, and they don’t like to just guess…they want to get to the root of the problem so that you get the correct answer and not a lot of maybe answers.

Comment: @pateksan You could be more specific about “types” or “technology” than linking the whole blooming website. I’m not sifting through that.

Comment: Well, I'm not helping you then. I'm afraid I don't have a service level agreement with you and you can only trust me to do the best I have the time for.

Comment: Hm tbf Sutherland's is somewhat expert reading. Can you meet halfway and [edit] in some photos of your bike to show the assembly from both sides?

Answer (score 1):

This normally means you haven't tightened both wheel axle nuts enough, holding the rear wheel in place.  Your leg strength, multiplied by the lever-action of the crank arm is giving you enough mechanical advantage to dislodge the axle.

Find at 15mm ring spanner for this - you can use an adjustable spanner/wrench/crescent but the ring spanner is better.

Loosen both nuts then pull the wheel backward until the chain is not slack.  You should have about 10mm of deflection in the chain.  Then tighten the right side wheel nut to "firm".

On the left side of the bike, use your left hand to position the wheel's rim equally between the chainstays and use your right hand to tighten the left-side axle nut.

That should be all it takes to secure the rear wheel in the right position.

---

You shouldn't have to mess with the coaster brake at all, other than make sure the reaction arm on the left hand side is still bolted on securely.

[The bike's manual](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/7286/9219/files/Cruiser_comfort_manual_2017.pdf?670) is not a lot of use in this situation.

Comment: Thanks, that seem to work! One note though – I’m American and I find the nuts are 5/8” and 11/16”. I’m mixing and matching my old coaster brake and the replacement parts.